# Eigenvalue answer check

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix \begin{equation} A=  \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -4 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \end{equation}

My solution to find the eigenvalue of this matrix :

Let $E$ be the eigenvalue of $A$ **iff** det$(EI - A ) = 0$ . Where $I$ is the identity matrix.

this comes down to : $( E-2 )(E-2)-4 = 0$

and this is : $E^2 -2E-2E+4-4 = 0 \Rightarrow E^2-4E = 0$

2nd degree equation, and its solutions are $4$ and $0$ which are our two eigenvalues.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. In spite of the horrible typing format, that much I could understand. Read here to learn to properly type mathematics in this site: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct, but you might as well have checked your answer on wolfram alpha...and it is quicker...it might be worthwhile checking the faq on what types of questions are better for this site, and I don't mean this in a discouraging way...;))